# OSX 10.9.5 cancel Finder operation causes dialog to never finish

Tags: macos, finder

Whenever I cancel a Finder operation (e.g. Duplicate), the progress window that pops up never finishes.
The Blue/White progress is animated, the `X` is of course disabled, and it says "Stopping" under the progress bar.  But it never stops.

All I can do is force quit it, which causes Finder to close and my Mac to reboot.

Anyone able to help me resolve this?

Opening the "Force Quit" option from the 'Apple' icon in the task bar but then cancelling made it go away.

Cheers,
Nap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try

```
killall Finder && open /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app
```